# mySQL, WHERE statement for a specific column

Tags: mysql, subquery

i have to select all flights from 'München' to 'Düsseldorf' and back. The table flightexecutions contains the informations to find the correct flight.

With my statement shown below, i am only able to select the FlightNo and the airport "from".

I dont know how to set up my SELECT statement in order to get the desired output which contains the FlightNo, from and to column.

```
--1)statements works correct, returns all FlightNo and origin "from"
SELECT flx.FlightNo, air.AirportName as `from`, air.AirportName as `to`
FROM flightexecution as flx, airport.airport as air
WHERE flx.ICAO_Code_Origin = air.ICAO_Code and (air.AirportName LIKE 'München (Franz Josef Strauß)'
OR air.AirportName LIKE 'Düsseldorf International');

--2)returns all flightNo and destination "to"
SELECT flx.FlightNo, air.AirportName as `to`
FROM flightexecution as flx, airport.airport as air
WHERE flx.ICAO_Code_Destination = air.ICAO_Code and (air.AirportName LIKE 'München (Franz Josef Strauß)'
      OR air.AirportName LIKE 'Düsseldorf International');

output1):

    FlightNo | from 
    -----------------
             |   

output2):

    FlightNo | to 
    -----------------
             |    




desired output:

FlightNo | from | to 
-------------------------
         |      |
```

[image]

```
ERR-Model:
```

Comment: You'll need to join to airport twice; I'd also recommend using actual JOIN syntax rather than the now-two-decades-out-of-favor comma "join" notation.

Comment: ...actually, you may need to join to `airport` 4 times (2 for "X to Y", and another 2 for "and back") _You might be able to get away with two, but that would probably involve aggregation that would just complicate things further._  Also, you might need to clarify what is meant by "and back"; does a flight that goes "X->Y->Z->Y->X" count  as "X to Y and back", or are departure times going to need to be consulted?

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with the inner join. To be more specific, every flight X->Y has its own FlightNo. Relating to your example "X->Y->Z->Y->X" every flight X->Y is a flight "to" and Y->X is a back flight, but we dont have flights "X->Y->Z" which are assambled by sub-flights "X->Y".

Comment: So we wouldn't carry a flight "X->Y->Z->Y->X", it would be X->Y,  Y->Z, Z->Y, Y->X.

Comment: Yes, I was using "X->Y->Z->Y->X" as shorthand for "X->Y, Y->Z, Z->Y, Y->X". What I meant was if flight A has those four "executions", or any intermediate "executions", is it still considered "X to Y and back"?

Comment: I see, back is the wrong word. It would be better to say all flights that connect airport X and Y in both ways, without any intermediate executions.

Comment: Yeah, the "and" made it a bit ambiguous. "or back" or "and flights back" probably would've been clearer; you can definitely do this with only two joins to `airport`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it; it joins all flightexecutions to their origin and destination airports independently, and then uses the WHERE conditions to filter the join results to only those with the desired endpoints.

```
SELECT fx.FlightNo, o.AirportName AS `from`, d.AirportName AS `to`
FROM flightexecution AS fx
INNER JOIN airport AS o ON fx.ICAO_Code_Origin = o.ICAO_Code
INNER JOIN airport AS d ON fx.ICAO_Code_Destination = d.ICAO_Code
WHERE (o.AirportName = 'München (Franz Josef Strauß)' AND d.AirportName = 'Düsseldorf International')
   OR (d.AirportName = 'München (Franz Josef Strauß)' AND o.AirportName = 'Düsseldorf International')
```

Sidenote: Due to how (poorly) MySQL handles `OR` conditions; if the database is large, you may have significantly better performance by UNIONing two versions of this query (one with each OR-part of the WHERE conditions).

Comment: Unfortunately the code returns an empy list. I tried to split the statement intot two statements, one for "from" and other for "to" and they return the same as the old statements i wrote. Maybe i have to use another join.

Comment: Or maybe the database has not flights with the given conditions.

Comment: The given code works fine! I really appreciate your help, it helped me understand the new syntax and it helped me solving the given problem!

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
WHERE (flx.ICAO_Code_Origin = air.ICAO_Code 
  and (air.AirportName LIKE 'München (Franz Josef Strauß)' 
    OR air.AirportName LIKE 'Düsseldorf International')) 
  AND (flx.ICAO_Code_Destination = air.ICAO_Code 
  and (air.AirportName LIKE 'München (Franz Josef Strauß)' 
    OR air.AirportName LIKE 'Düsseldorf International'));
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work because the this `WHERE` statement we would search for all FlightNo which have ` ICAO_Code_Destination = ICAO_Code_Origin`

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT flx.FlightNo AS flightname, air.AirportName as`from`, airTo.AirportName as`to`FROM flightexecution as flx, airport.airport as air,airport.airport as airTo,  flightexecution as flxFrom WHERE (flx.ICAO_Code_Origin = air.ICAO_Code and (air.AirportName LIKE 'München (Franz Josef Strauß)'OR air.AirportName LIKE 'Düsseldorf International')) AND (flxFrom.ICAO_Code_Destination = airTo.ICAO_Code and (airTo.AirportName LIKE 'München (Franz Josef Strauß)' OR airTo.AirportName LIKE 'Düsseldorf International'));`

Try this